# Navigable Set ceiling on negative number

Tags: java, set

According to [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#ceiling(E)) the ceiling  should return number greater then or equal to the given element or null, in the code below why ceiling of -12 is -12?

```
NavigableSet<Integer> sset = new TreeSet<>();
        sset.add(-12);
        sset.add(-13);
        sset.add(-11);
        sset.add(24);

         //why the ceiling of -12 is -12? there are number greater then -12 in the set
        System.out.println(sset.ceiling(-12)); 
        System.out.println(sset.ceiling(0));
        System.out.println(sset.ceiling(24));
        System.out.println(sset.ceiling(100));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the documentation link you mentionned:

> Returns the **least element** in this set greater than or equal to the
>   given element, or null if there is no such element.

Comment: I am a bit confused so why sset.floor(-12) also return -12?

Comment: `floor` is the closest element <=, `ceiling` is the closest element >=.  If there is an equal element, both `floor` and `ceiling` will return it.

Comment: You have 3 elements greater than or equal to -12: -12, -11, 24. -12 is the **least** of those _3 elements_. You have 2 elements lower than or equal to -12: -12 and -13. -12 is the **greatest** of those _2 elements_.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is a Sorted TREE and the method returns *least element* in this set greater than or equal to the given element

Try to understand this method which actually returns you the ceiling.

```
final Entry<K,V> getCeilingEntry(K key) {
        Entry<K,V> p = root;
        while (p != null) {
            int cmp = compare(key, p.key);
            if (cmp < 0) {
                if (p.left != null)
                    p = p.left;
                else
                    return p;
            } else if (cmp > 0) {
                if (p.right != null) {
                    p = p.right;
                } else {
                    Entry<K,V> parent = p.parent;
                    Entry<K,V> ch = p;
                    while (parent != null && ch == parent.right) {
                        ch = parent;
                        parent = parent.parent;
                    }
                    return parent;
                }
            } else
                return p;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The following will return you -11 and -13 as they are least about greater than or equal to the given element.

```
        System.out.println(sset.ceiling(-11));
        System.out.println(sset.ceiling(-13));
```